# BMI Calculator Java incorrect output

Tags: java

I am trying to code a basic command line BMI Calculator in Java and for some reason every time I run the code and enter my height and weight, 0 is outputted. Please help me understand where I have made a mistake.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Chap2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your height in inches: ");
        int myHeight = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your weight in lbs: ");
        int myWeight = reader.nextInt();
        int Bmi = (myWeight/myHeight/myHeight)*703;
        System.out.println("Your BMI is " + Bmi + ".");
}
}
```

And my output is as follows:

```
Enter your height in inches: 
68
Enter your weight in lbs: 
180
Your BMI is 0.
```

Comment: Things will be different if you change to `(703*myWeight/myHeight/myHeight)`. The root cause is described in the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing `int` with `int`, thus the result is a rounded `int`.
Cast to double before calculation to get exact results.

```
double bmi = ((double) myWeight / myHeight / myHeight) * 703;
```

Comment: why does dividing int with int return 0?

Comment: Cause the result will be a `int` again and this will be rounded. The frist calculation is `0` then and thus the next is that also. Read further here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Comment: And btw do not capitalize your variable names! :)